# Get Foreign Objects instead of QuerySet of List of ID's

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, postgresql, django-orm

**single line of code to get the Foreign Key objects instead of QuerySet of UUID's.**

I have three Models,

```
Student, College, Member
```

Models are defined similar to below

```
class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128)

class College(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Member(models.Model):
    student= models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name="students", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    college= models.ForeignKey(College, related_name="colleges", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Where Member contains of Student and College as Foreign Key fields

Now I want to get all the Students who belong to a particular College based on college_id which should be filtered from the Member model

How I am doing now

```
student_ids = Member.objects.filter(college_id=college_id).values("student")
```

Now `students` is a QuerySet of list of UUID's of Student

As I need actual Student objects instead of QuerySet List of UUID's

```
students = Student.objects.filter(id__in=[str(uid) for uid in student_ids])
```

**I feel this is an improper way. Can anyone suggest a single line of code to get the Foreign Key objects instead of QuerySet of UUID's. Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Student.objects.filter(students__college_id=college_id)
```

The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) however is the name of the relation in *reverse*. It thus makes more sense to rename these for example to:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student,
        related_name='members',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    college = models.ForeignKey(
        College,
        related_name='members',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

then you filter with:

```
Student.objects.filter(members__college_id=college_id)
```

You can also span a *conceptual* [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) between a `College` and `Student`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    colleges = models.ManyToManyField(
        'College',
        related_name='students'
        through='Member'
    )
```

Then you can filter with:

```
Student.objects.filter(colleges=college_id)
```